# Method to prevent iTunes from opening app store links without browser hacks?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

Looking for a way to prevent web links to the iTunes store from launching iTunes. Yes, I've seen the browser hacks available to prevent this. However, I've seen links to apps on iTunes that do not launch the iTunes application. Example: Home Depot (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-home-depot/id342527639?mt=8). And here is one that does load iTunes: http://www.itunes.com/apps/turfpath. Can't seem to find a setting in Itunes connect to disable this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't see anything special about the home depot link, but did you try replacing your app id in the same?

Comment: I did, but no luck. That's the thing; there seem to be nothing special about these URLs and I can't find anything in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that removing the query string from the url prevents iTunes from opening.

Comment: It doesn't. May be it has changed since you answered in 2013! With/Without query params, it still opens iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same thing, and finally found that the iTunes link maker finally did the trick:

https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/us/

The final link it created for my app looks like this (to be clear, for me *this does not open itunes, it just opens the browser to my app*):

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ioverlander/id894352689?mt=8&uo=4

Before, I had tried a link like this, which *did* open iTunes:

http://itunes.com/app/ioverlander

Maybe you can try this and see if it works for you?

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It still applies in 2019

Answer (score 1):

We can use:

**`&Is=0`**

in iTunes URL to open any of the app link in browser rather then to in iTunes/App store.

Comment: Didn't work for me, it still launched iTunes. Example: https://itunes.apple.com/mx/app/autos-sonora/id924626554&Is=0